# Cordova XmlHttpRequest to IP Address is Blocked

Tags: ios, cordova, printing, cors

Your advise or recommended solution is welcome.

I have a Cordova app that uses a RESTful service. The app needs to send a request to a printer at an IP address that is specified at run time. The printer is a Star Micronics thermal printer that is WebPRNT enabled (it has a web server that accepts a POST request with the print job).

Printing and the RESTful service work when run in Chrome. It fails when I deploy it wrapped in Cordova on an iPad. I can open the app in Safari on the iPad and successfully send the print job. Cordova seems to be blocking the POST to the printer for some reason. The RESTful service is an external service (CORS) that uses a domain name. The printer is using an IP. Both use POST methods. Only the printer fails.

I am using RestAngular for the communication between the app and the RESTful service. I am using [Star Micronics' SDK](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/ZipFile.aspx?sat2=220&id=220&type=4) (JavaScript using bare XmlHttpRequest) to send the request to the printer. I attempted to send a request to the server using RestAngular, Angular's $http, and JQuery. None worked.

The error responseText is null and http code is -1. This request was blocked at the exit gate and never made it to the printer.

Cordova version: 5.3.3
App: HTML5 + AngualrJS 1.4.3 (this call uses raw XmlHttpRequest)

Cordova Configuration (config.xml):

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="content:///*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I've tried several variations of the above, specifiying the IP explicity, etc. Nothing worked.

HTML Meta Content Security Policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src * http://IP_HERE; ">
```

I've tried several variations of Content Security Policy in conjunction with the settings in config.xml. Nothing worked.

Printer replies with these headers when I send it from the browser:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → origin, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
```

Here is the code that makes the call (cropped StarWebPrintTrader.js). The full JS file is included in [Star Micronics' SDK](http://www.starmicronics.com/support/ZipFile.aspx?sat2=220&id=220&type=4):

```
var c=null;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    c=new XMLHttpRequest;
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    c=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else{
    if(this.onError)
        this.onError({status:10001,responseText:"XMLHttpRequest is not supported."});
    return
}
try{
    c.open("POST",b,!0)
}
catch(f){
    if(this.onError)
        this.onError({status:10002,responseText:f.message});
    return
}
c.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/xml; charset=UTF-8");
c.onreadystatechange=function(){alert('state change')};
c.send();
```

Comment: Are you using iOS 9?

Comment: Yes. I'm using iOS 9.

Comment: OK please see my answer you will be coming up against App Transport Security configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on iOS 9 you are probably coming up against App Transport Security restrictions which by default won't allow connections to non SSL endpoints regardless of what Cordova's Content Security Policy is set to.  This was new on iOS9.

In this case you need to set both an App Transport Security exception AND configure the Content Security Policy to also allow access to the same hosts.

To configure App Transport Security open up your project's -Info.plist file and add:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Which disables ATS and allows connections to any http host without SSL.  If you want to limit to a specific host or set of hosts and you know these at build time you can use this form:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
      <key>myhost.mydomain.com</key>
      <dict>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

And specify a list of exception domains as needed.

There's a [blog post here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/) that explains this in more detail.

Comment: It was both ATS and CSP. I added NSAppTransportSecurity to my plist. This still did not fix the problem, but was important. I then read the blog. My problem was that the printer does not support https and Cordova's default CSP was restricting connection. Printing started working when I removed the Content Security Policy meta tag. I then went back to the Cordova default Content Security Policy and modified it to work for my app: content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' data: gap:; connect-src: *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'". Thank you Simon!